# Returning configurable_options and variants are null for configurable products in custom product collection graphql query

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, graphql, magento-graphql

I have `sellerProducts` Query and `SellerProducts` type has product interface. When i call  SellerProducts query it returns configurable_options and variants are null for configurable products in custom product collection.

```
type Query { 

    sellerProducts(
        input: SellerInput @doc(description: "Getting seller products details.")
        ): SellerProducts @resolver(class:"Custom\\MpGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SellerProducts") @doc(description: "Return query of marketplace sellers products")

}
input SellerInput @doc(description: "Filters to fetch Seller") {
    seller_id: String @doc(description: "Seller Id")
}
type SellerProducts  @doc(description: "") {
    details: [Details] @doc(description: "")
    products: [ProductInterface]
}
```

*Seller product resolver code.*

```
$sellerProducts = $this->getSellerProducts($sellerId);
        foreach ($sellerProducts as $product) {
            $productData[] = [
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'type_id' => $product->getTypeId(),
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'url_key' => $product->getUrlKey(),
                'model' => $product
            ];
        }

   return [
            'products' => $productData,
        ];



public function getSellerProducts($sellerId)
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['in' => [2, 4]])
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->addStoreFilter(1);
    return $collection;
}
```

*Graphql payload*

```
{
  sellerProducts(input: { seller_id: "115921" }) {
    products {
        name
        sku
        image {
          url
          label
        }
        ... on ConfigurableProduct {
        configurable_options {
          id
          attribute_id
          label
          position
          use_default
          attribute_code
        
          values {
            value_index
            label
            swatch_data{
              value
            }
          }
          product_id
  
        }
        variants {
          product {
            id
            name
            sku
            attribute_set_id
            ... on PhysicalProductInterface {
              weight
            }
            media_gallery{
              url
              position
            }
            price_range{
              minimum_price{
                regular_price{
                  value
                  currency
                }
              }
            }
          }
          attributes {
            uid
            label
            code
            value_index
          }
        }
      }
      }
    
  }
}
```

*Response*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days of investigation i have found the solution.
in product data `entity_id` is missing. that was the issue. I have passed `entity_id` in array and it's working fine. hope it help someone .

```
 $productData[] = [
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'type_id' => $product->getTypeId(),
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'url_key' => $product->getUrlKey(),
                'model' => $product,
                'entity_id' => $product->getId()
               
            ];
```